# PowerShell Array issue with variable

Tags: powershell

I am using Powershell and I have a variable like this:

```
$E = "Apple"
```

When I run `$E[0]` I expect to see `Apple`, but it shows `A` only. How can I do that?

Comment: `$E` is a `string`, not an array (ignoring that a `string` is an array of `char`s.  `$E[0]` _is_ `"A"`, and `$E` is `"Apple"`.

Answer (score 1):

`$E = "Apple"` Is not an array, it is a simple string declaration so when you try to get index 0 of that string (or char array) you are returning the first character in the character array:

```
 0   1   2   3   4
[A] [P] [P] [L] [E]
```

The define an array you need a second item (separated by a comma):

`$E = "Apple", "Orange"`

Then you can use `$E[0]` to return **Apple** like you are wanting.

Comment: $T=@($E) is the solution. $T[0]

Comment: You don't need two elements to make an array; `$E = ,"Apple"` is a one-element array.  You don't even need one element; `$E = @()` is an empty array.